# Percent sign % not working in crontab

Tags: bash, curl, cron

I have a cron issue with `curl`:

```
curl -w "%{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null -s http://myurl.com >> ~/log
```

works great and add a line in log file with total_time.

But the same line with cron doesn't do anything.

It's not a path problem because `curl http://myurl.com >> ~/log` works.

Comment: Have you tried escaping `%`? `curl -w "\%{time_total}\n"` ...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cron error with using backquotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444595/cron-error-with-using-backquotes)

Comment: For general `cron` troubleshooting, please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`%` is a special character for `crontab`. From `man 5 crontab`:

> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be
>   run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a  newline  or  a
>   "%" character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified
>   in the SHELL variable of the cronfile.  **A "%" character in the
>   command, unless escaped with a backslash (\), will be changed into
>   newline characters,  and all data after the first % will be sent to
>   the command as standard input**.

So you need to escape the `%` character:

```
curl -w "%{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null -s http://myurl.com >> ~/log
```

to

```
curl -w "\%{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null -s http://myurl.com >> ~/log
         ^
```