# How to create file name of Feed Export dynamically using scrapy command

Tags: linux, scrapy

This is command to run my scraper.

```
scrapy crawl monitor -a filename="ScrapeProject.csv" -o filename.csv
```

It runs and saves the scraped data into `filename.csv`

I want to schedule as cronjob I want filename.csv to be the current datetime the scraper ran.

I tried with back-ticks but didnt work

```
scrapy crawl monitor -a filename="ScrapeProject.csv" -o `date`.csv
```

Also tried like that

```
scrapy crawl monitor -a filename="ScrapeProject.csv" -o "date".csv
```

EDIT:

Below is the command I ran upon @dps recommendation but it prompts me to enter something?

```
root@ubuntu:/home/mani/pricemonitor# scrapy crawl monitor -a filename="ScrapeProject.csv" -o `date +\%m`.`date +\%d`.`date +\%y`.csv`
> 
>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scrapy Feed Exports also understand (some built-in) [storage URI parameters](http://file:///home/paul/src/scrapy/docs/build/html/topics/feed-exports.html#storage-uri-parameters) out of the box.

`%(time)s` is one of them.

So you can do something like:

```
scrapy crawl monitor -a filename="ScrapeProject.csv" -o '%(time)s.csv'
```

which will create output files in the form `YYYY-mm-ddTHH-MM-SS`, e.g. `2017-05-11T12-12-18.csv`.

Internally, [`time` is converted](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/d8672689761f0bb6c0550a841f35534265e87fee/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py#L263) using `datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat().replace(':', '-')`.

**Note:** you can use any spider attribute in your Feed URI (what you set with `-o`). Remember that [any spider argument](http://file:///home/paul/src/scrapy/docs/build/html/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments) (stuff you can add to the command line with `-a key=value`) will be available as spider argument (as strings).

Comment: Damnn you are so unbelievable that I had to revert my accepted answer from @dps to yours ... ....

Comment: **shakes fist** can't win them all, nice answer.

Comment: minor tip for windows users (tagged linux i know this was the first result!), I could only get this working with double quotes, but it works like a charm. *tips hat*

Answer (score 4):

You aren't trying to apply any formatting to the date command in your cron job are you?  You need to escape percentage signs for cron, i.e.

```
`date +\%m`.`date +\%d`.`date +\%y`.tar.gz
```

See: [Percent sign % not working in crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123367/percent-sign-not-working-in-crontab)

Also, does it work from the command line when you don't use cron (with the ticked `` `date` ``  )?