# A crontab fails to run a task with a date command

Tags: date, cron, command-substitution

In a project, I am trying to run a command that processes data from the day before (a rather common use case).

I am running it from a Docker container (python:3.11 derived) and therefore a Linux system, but it's unlikely to be related to this specific system.

In order to find the previous date, I use the following command:

```
date +%F --date="1 day ago"
```

The `+%F` (full date) formats the output as `YYYY-MM-DD`.
(the --date option is GNU-specific. On BSD derived systems, including MacOS, the equivalent would be -v1d)

In order to troubleshoot the problem, I prepared a small crontab with the following tasks (in my container, it is to be put at /etc/cron.d/crontab)

```
* * * * * root echo "Hello World" 1>> /some/path/log/hello_world.log 2>&1
* * * * * root echo Hello `date` 1>> /some/path/log/hello_today.log 2>&1
* * * * * root echo Hello $(date +%F --date="1 day ago") 1>> /some/path/log/hello_yesterday.log 2>&1
```

Rather oddly, the `hello_world.log` and `hello_today.log` work, but the `hello_yesterday.log` is not created.

At first I was suspecting a problem related with command substitutions, but the second task (`hello_today.log`) works, and its content is correct.
Then, I wondered if it could be the syntax of command substitution (backticks against dollar-parentheses), since the dollar-parentheses syntax was not supported by legacy versions of shells. I verified that both syntaxes work with `hello_today.log`

What is mind-blowing is that the third task doesn't even create the log file, so no error message stored in this file can help. It's like if the line was skipped entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the solution in another Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27125439/11394968)

I have still decided to share this question/answer for this specific case, for it could help other people.

The problem had nothing to do with command substitutions in crontab, but simply with the percent sign. It has a special meaning in crontab and must be escaped with a backslash when used by other commands.

In this specific case, the task must be rewritten:

```
* * * * * root echo Hello $(date +\%F --date="1 day ago") 1>> /some/path/log/hello_yesterday.log 2>&1
```

Comment: In general it's good practice to create script with commands and execute it in `cron` instead of run bunch of commands in `cron` itself.