# cron task not writing to file

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I'm trying to append the current date and time to a log file every minute using cron. I want the date and time to be formatted in a specific way.

This works:

```
* * * * * date >> /home/user/time1.txt
```

This doesn't:

```
* * * * * date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S >> /home/user/time2.txt
```

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: This is the first troubleshooting point in the [cron tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron error with using backquotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444595/cron-error-with-using-backquotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `cron` treats `%` as newlines. You need to escape them

From `crontab POSIX man` page:

> Percent-signs (`%`) in the command, unless escaped with backslash `\`, 
>   will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first `%`  will  be
>   sent to the command as standard input.

```
* * * * * date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S >> /home/user/time2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

escape `%` with \ and then it should work.